# Scale iFrame css width 100% like an image

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design

I want to scale an iFrame through CSS to `width: 100%`, and the height should scale proportionally to the width.

With an `<img>` tag this works fine.

Both the image and the iFrame have defined width and height in the html.

Here some examples:

```html
<html>
    <style>
        #a{ width: 500px; }
        img{ width: 100%; height: auto }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="a">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/" width="200" height="150" />
        </div>
    </body>
```

This works great on images, but I would like the same behaviour for iFrames:

```html
<html>
    <style>
        #a{ width: 900px; background: grey;}
        iframe{ width: 100%; height: auto }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="a">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RksyMaJiD8Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The iFrame renders 100% wide but does not scale it's height proportional like the image does.

Comment: What do you have so far?  Can you make a jsfiddle? Lets see your code.

Answer (score 116):

Big difference between an image and an iframe is the fact that an image keeps its aspect-ratio. You could combine an image and an iframe with will result in a responsive iframe.
Hope this answerers your question.

Check this link for example : http://jsfiddle.net/Masau/7WRHM/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <!-- a transparent image is preferable -->
        <img class="ratio" src="http://placehold.it/16x9"/>
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WsFWhL4Y84Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <p>Please scale the "result" window to notice the effect.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body        {height:100%;}
.wrapper         {width:80%;height:100%;margin:0 auto;background:#CCC}
.h_iframe        {position:relative;}
.h_iframe .ratio {display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}
.h_iframe iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
```

note: This only works with a fixed aspect-ratio.

Comment: One more note, an image is not necessary (at least in modern'ish browsers).  The padding-top (set padding to aspect ratio) trick works: 
<div style="width:100%;padding-top:75.4%">
 <iframe style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;"></iframe>
</div>

Comment: @ansiart Your padding top trick does not work if you need to set a `max-width`. Also, you forgot `position:relative` on the container.

Comment: Whoop. Thanks for that. Got me out of jam trying to dynamically resize an iFrame on a mobile version of a site. Vote: up :)

Comment: Genius, saved my skin.

Comment: @ansiart yours is the most elegant and minimal solution I've come across so far. Thank you!

Comment: @ansiart @Walf To set `max-width` with your code, simply wrap it in another div: `<div style="max-width:520px"><div style="position:relative;padding-top:75.4%"> <iframe style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;"></iframe></div></div>`

Comment: Ugh.. we are past using transparent images for layout, keep scrolling as Simone Lazzari answer is superior!

Comment: Same principle without image request: Use inline SVG: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:100%;" viewBox="0 0 500 60"></svg>`

Answer (score 69):

I suppose this is a cleaner approach.
It works with inline `height` and `width` properties (I set random value in the fiddle to prove that) and with CSS `max-width` property.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe height="2" width="2" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WsFWhL4Y84Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <p>Please scale the "result" window to notice the effect.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body        {height: 100%;}
.wrapper         {width: 80%; max-width: 600px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: #CCC}
.h_iframe        {position: relative; padding-top: 56%;}
.h_iframe iframe {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7WRHM/1001/

Comment: I wanted to add some more visibility to this answer, as it seems like a clear winner. The previous answer involving adding a hidden img to trigger scaling is clever, but forcing an additional http request, specifically on mobile, is far from ideal. This pure CSS answer is a much better approach.

Comment: padding-top should be 56.25% or the video is wider than 16/9

Comment: @Simone, off-topic but yes I personally prefer the css only approach. A good read is : http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

For IE7 support check  http://alistapart.com/d/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/example4.html

Answer (score 30):

I like this solution best. Simple, scalable, responsive. The idea here is to create a zero-height outer div with bottom padding set to the aspect ratio of the video. The iframe is scaled to 100% in both width and height, completely filling the outer container. The outer container automatically adjusts its height according to its width, and the iframe inside adjusts itself accordingly.

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:0px; padding-bottom:56.25%;">
    <iframe style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RksyMaJiD8Y">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

The only variable here is the padding-bottom value in the outer div. It's 75% for 4:3 aspect ratio videos, and 56.25% for widescreen 16:9 aspect ratio videos.

Comment: This breaks if the div's parent is not exactly the same width.

Comment: @Walf - how? The widths are all 100% relative to the parent.

Comment: Because these sizing wrappers are typically placed adjacent to other content elements in the DOM which rely on padding to size them appropriately. As a result, doing only a single wrapper to fix the aspect ratio makes it more fragile, and that embed can either appear wider than the other content, or overflow, or both: https://jsfiddle.net/bjvLzkq7/ It's a really common issue which you've likely seen yourself on a mobile device, on sites that embed YouTube videos. Often the aspect is okay, but the video spills over the right edge same distance as the other content's padding.

Answer (score 9):

You could use viewport units here instead of %. Like this:

```
iframe {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 56.25vw; /* height/width ratio = 315/560 = .5625 */
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/xs8Lnug1/3/) (Resize to see the effect)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.a {
  max-width: 560px;
  background: grey;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
iframe {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 56.25vw;
  /* 315/560 = .5625 */
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/560/315/" width="560" height="315" />
</div>

<div class="a">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RksyMaJiD8Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I think vw are not suited for this. http://jsfiddle.net/bancaf/615y5aou/ here, in a semplified example based on your code, the iframe height stays locked to a default 150px (browser default min height for an iframe I think). What am I missing?

Comment: This solution is fantastic because it doesn't require the HTML to have any extra tags and there's no JavaScript involved.

Answer (score 3):

@Anachronist is closest here, @Simone not far off. The caveat with percentage padding on an element is that it's based on its *parent's* width, not its own. If the width is different to your container (and often is), the aspect will be wrong.

The most bulletproof answer is to use **two** wrapping divs:

```css
body {
  /* for this demo */
  background: lightgray;
}
.fixed-aspect-wrapper {
  /* can accept any padding to match its siblings in the DOM */
  padding: 0;
  /* width can be anything or nothing, it doesn't matter */
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.fixed-aspect-padder {
  /* this stretches the height of first wrapper but maintains a natural width at the correct ratio */
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* last padding dimension is (100 * height / width) of item to be scaled,
     here is the common 16:9 ratio */
  padding: 0 0 56.25%;
}
.whatever-needs-the-fixed-aspect {
  /* this fills the available space */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  /* for this demo */
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-aspect-wrapper">
  <div class="fixed-aspect-padder">
    <iframe class="whatever-needs-the-fixed-aspect" src="/"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and is so clearly explained.

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions worked for me inside a Weebly "add your own html" box.  Not sure what they are doing with their code.  But I found this solution at https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/   and it works perfectly.

CSS

```
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

/* 4x3 Aspect Ratio */
.iframe-container-4x3 {
  padding-top: 75%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/106466360" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Not only did this work for me...but I was also able to add one more additional wrapper div around it so I could replace an <img> in a standard Angular Material Mat-Card and it filled up the entire space like the <img> without having to dink around with their standard  settings! Thanks! 

.MatCardVid {
    position: relative;
    left: -16px;
    width: calc(100% + 32px);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
//    background-color: lightcyan;
}

Comment: This is functionally the same as the current top answer, and like that one, this also breaks if the element containing the `.iframe-container' is wider than it.