# Html5 frames alternative

Tags: html, css, iframe, frames

In my html5/css3 website I need to load a `<form>` from an external host/server and display it somewhere on my page. I've read that frames are deprecated. What would be an alternative?, How would I do it?

thanks

Comment: Framesets might be deprecated.  Iframes are just fine.  In fact, [framesets were deprecated in favor of iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Iframes for this:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/form.php" name="myform"> // or src="path/to/your/form.php"

// the content of your Iframe goes here...

</iframe>
```

http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_iframe_tag.cfm

http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/html5-iframe-attributes.htm

Comment: is there a way to make the iframe take up as much space in the parent as its content?. I would like for the iframe to adjust to it's content.

Comment: I found this on stackoverflow. It's a responsive-ish Iframe that takes up 100% of it's parent http://stackoverflow.com/a/12121929/1379394