# Responsive iFrames with Image Only

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently working on a project for a class at school where I'm setting up a webpage to mimic a chatroom. I have a sidebar for users in the chatroom and the chatroom itself, which are both iframes with images contained within them. I want the iframes to be responsive; as the viewport size changes, i'd like the iframe and the image within it to resize as well.

I currently have both iframes floated to the left and added some spacing to make it look more chatroom-esque. I've visited the following link: [Scale iFrame css width 100% like an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122249/scale-iframe-css-width-100-like-an-image), however this is different than what I'm trying to do bc their using an embeded video, not a scrolling image. Anyone have a fix for this? I've been messing around with styles... check out the webpage at www.westerosnet.jaylaiche.com.

Additionally, here's HTML and CSS:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Welcome to Westeros.Net</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to Westeros.net</h1>
            <h2>Your source for virtual strategy, betrayal, and more!</h2>
            <iframe src="sidebar.jpg"></iframe>
            <iframe id="room" src="chatroom.jpg"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <h3>To learn the real events of this scene, click <a href="http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Wedding">here</a>.</h3>
            <h3 id="copyright">Page created by Jay Laiche for Traci Gardner's ENGL 3844 Remixing A Story.</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


CSS:
    body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

iframe {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 800px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dotted #330099;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#room {
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 600px;
}

.container {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use iframes to place those images? Just use the <img> tag and work with width and max-width!

Comment: I want the images to scroll like a real chatroom would.

Comment: I don't really get it, but set overflow:scroll; to the div where the images shall be inside and then you can scroll perfectly. I guess you just placed the overflow declaration at the wrong place (iframe instead of div.container). And don't forget to give the div a height!

Comment: Go to http://www.westerosnet.jaylaiche.com.

Comment: I want it to stay exactly like that, but be responsive.

Comment: Then use width instead of max-width