# Responsive IFrame to display content from External Document

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an `iframe` to display the content of a .htm file, which is present in another location. The document loads perfectly while on a desktop browser.

But while on a mobile version, the content of the document is not displayed completely.

I am looking for a responsive iframe for both mobile and desktop views.

**HTML**

```
<iframe
    id="ifrm"
    src="URL.htm"
    width="100%"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    height="1450px"
    style="padding-top: 0px; float: left;" target="_blank"
/>
```

I referred these links, but unfortunately they didn't help:

[Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height)

[Scale iFrame css width 100% like an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122249/scale-iframe-css-width-100-like-an-image)

Comment: Is the target page responsive too?

Comment: Yes. The page is responsive

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/6txMa/)** with bootstrap website in iframe

Make sure you have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

in `<head>` of your document.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/8a4sS/3/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="iframe">
    <iframe src="http://a.rgbimg.com/cache1wZTwK/users/m/mi/micromoth/600/oIejAt8.jpg" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.iframe {
    position:relative;
}
iframe, object, embed {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```