# How can I center a youtube video while keeping it responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I'm working on making a mobile version for the landing page of my game. I have a youtube trailer in it which should scale according to the website size while keeping centered. But it don't. You can see yourself on my website http://www.zatackaonline.net by scaling the browser size down.

I tried using this code which I found on another post on StackOverflow. This code will instead fill the whole screen which I don't want it to. Is there any way I could shrink it to be 50% size while keeping the embeded iFrame video position centered?

```
/*main.css*/

.video-container { 
position: relative; /* keeps the aspect ratio */ 
padding-bottom: 56%; /* fine tunes the video positioning */ 
padding-top: 60px; 
overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shrink a Youtube video to responsive width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844500/shrink-a-youtube-video-to-responsive-width)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to get the iframe to the correct width without changing your code too much, you could use the `vw` unit (here's [some info](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) on viewport units):

```
#contentframe iframe{
    width:50vw;
}
```

Secondly, to center the container, set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` values to `auto`, and specify its width:

```
#contentframe{
    /* left:294px */ // REMOVE
    width: 50vw;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Remember to wrap all this in the right media query and it should do the trick!

**Edit** About the `left:294px`: I find it becomes confusing when trying to use these absolute values in responsive websites, maybe using percentage values as much as possible will make things easier for you.

**Edit 2** Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EB57H/1/

**Edit 3** <strike>To keep the ratio while resizing, remove the `width` and `height` attribute from the `iframe` source: http://jsfiddle.net/EB57H/2/</strike>

```
<iframe width=560" height="315" src="...
// BECOMES
<iframe src="...
```

That wasn't working well, here's [another not very elegant solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EB57H/4/).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make the height of the video also scale when resizing?

Comment: I updated my answer with a little more help. There is another technique if your video is embedded dynamically [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122249/scale-iframe-css-width-100-like-an-image)

Comment: Thanks, If I want it bigger then.. How can I make that? :)

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it. Just changed vw to 60 and 60 :)

Comment: With this, you can programmatically set the height for the iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/EB57H/3/

Comment: Thanks! would upvote 100x times if i could :) Why you say it's not elegant?

Comment: Glad I could be of help :) It's not elegant because in the example you have to set the 50/60/70vw values manually three times to change it. There would probably be a *sexier* way to do this with a touch more thinking!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58227/discussion-between-sir-celsius-and-user3534757).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
left:594px;
```

Use :

```
text-align:center;
```

In the `contentframe` css style

For the responsive size, remove height and width from the `<iframe>` and add the css rule `width:80%`  for example to the iframe

Comment: I did what you say and added this: <div class="video-container" style="text-align:center;">. This will center it but the video will not resize. Am I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I mixed all the answers to build an optimized solution, with center, responsive and max-height to avoid the video to take all the page if on a wide screen.

CSS:

```
.video-container {
  width: 70vw;
  max-width: 560px ;
  margin:auto;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  width: 70vw;
  max-width: 560px ;
  height:calc((9/16)*70vw);
  max-height:calc((9/16)*560px);
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe
      width="853"
      height="480"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4JkIs37a2JE"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```